# Making set length text box

Tags: boxes

LaTex noob here. Im looking for a simple way to make a box in latex that **won't expand to fit the text.** I have been trying to use a minipage within a fbox but it keeps expanding. I have been trying to make a 3in by 5in box

Comment: should it break the text?

Comment: I looking for it so when it reaches the end of the box, it would start a new line, so i believe so.

Comment: Parbox has three optional parameters the first [t,b,c] locates the baseline, the second specifies the height, and the third [t,b,c,s] locates the text inside the box.  [s] stands for span which basically stretches the text to fill the box (requires at least something inside which stretches).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code uses the `fitting` library of the `tcolorbox` package to create a `3in` by `5in` box with never expands this size. The text content is rescaled to fit into this box.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[fitting]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcboxfit{\mybox}[1][]{%
  fit algorithm=hybrid*,
  width=3in,
  height=5in,
  sharp corners,
  colframe=black,colback=white,
  size=fbox,#1
}

\begin{document}

\mybox{Testbox}

\mybox{Testbox with some more text, more text, more text, more text, more text.}

\mybox{\lipsum[1]}

\mybox{\lipsum[1-2]}

\mybox{\lipsum[1-3]}

\mybox{\lipsum[1-4]}

\end{document}
```

This output for the last four boxes is:

[image]

Comment: How to center the text inside?

Comment: Add `valign=center`